# Combinatorics question: 20 lines

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

You have 20 different lines. You also have  people, and these people are lined up in an ordered manner in front of these 20 lines. p = b+c+d where b and c are identical and all d are distinguishable. You need to determine how many different ways these  people can be arranged in front of the 20 lines, considering that some lines may have no people in them.

**My approach:**

I thought that because $b$ are all the same, and $c$ are all the same, d are all distinguishable, and the lines are ordered, then using stars-and-bars, $C(19+b,b) \times C(19+c,c) \times 20^d \times P(20,2+d)$ gives the total number of ways.

I would appreciate help to see if my logic is correct and if not, how to approach this problem and formulate it.

Comment: Doesn't the order in line matter to the count?

Comment: No.  It's more nuanced than that.

Comment: I can't easily do so in these comments.  In its stead, here's a hint on how I would approach it: first solve the problem when assuming all $p$ people are distinguishable.

Comment: Paint a distinct number on each person.  We can erase the numbers later.

Comment: @SparshGupta: Why do you delete a question after it has been answered ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, that method doesn't work because it doesn't consider order within a line.

Instead, as I said, let's assume all $p$ people are distinguishable.
In this situation, we can choose how many people should be at each station using stars-and-bars.  This gives $C(19+p,p)$ ways we can choose the size of each station's line.

Then, independently, we may permute all $p$ people in $p!$ ways, and once we have how many people are at each station and the order of the people, we can assign them, in order, to each station.

In particular, this means we can assign the $p$ distinguishable people to the $20$ stations in $p!\cdot C(19+p,p)$ ways.

"*But it's not true all $p$ were distinguishable*" -- Right, let's take care of that now.

Let's assume only the $b$ blue men are indistinguishable now (that is, all $c$ circus performers are still distinguishable).  Then since they can be permuted $b!$ ways within all the blue men, each way we can line everyone up such that the blue men are indistinguishable will correspond to $b!$ of the ways we lined everyone up when we assumed everyone was distinguishable.  Further, each of the $b!$ permutations collapses to the same situation, so we can count this by dividing our previous answer by $b!$, giving $p! \cdot C(19+p,p) / b!$ ways.

The same process happens when we make the $c$ circus performers indistinguishable from one another, so when we do so, we just need to divide by the number of ways they can be permuted among themselves, $c!$, to find the final answer:
$$\frac{p! \cdot C(19+p,p)}{b! c!} = \frac{(19+p)!}{19!b!c!}$$

Comment: @SparshGupta Please review the answer again.  I had to fix my initial draft, which was off by a factor of $19!$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring: My apologies, I should have posted against the question, I am deleting from here.